# Why are some networking APIs able to accept remote connections and others are not?

Tags: windows, tomcat, networking, wininet, windows-firewall

I'm at a loss to explain this behavior with web servers on windows. It's in a domain environment with windows firewall set as domain policy.

- local web servers - both as localhost:port and FQDM:port

  - Tomcat  OK
  - IIS  OK
  - WEBrick OK
  - Jenkin's server - OK
- remote access - using FQDM:port

  - Tomcat  No connection
  - IIS   No connection
  - WEBrick **OK**
  - Jenkin's server - **OK**

What I don't understand what WEBRick and the server Jenkins uses to accept remote connections.

Are there other diagnostics I should look into?
Is it possible to configure Tomcat to use a similar approach?

Comment: Are there any entries at all in the Tomcat and IIS error/access logs? If you tracert/traceroute to the machine, do you get a complete trace?  Are the servers pingable? Does the firewall log the drop for IIS/Tomcat? Can you post your Tomcat and IIS configs?

Comment: Do you mean to say that all of those are on localhost, when you access them inside your firewall? But only WEBrick and Jenkins can be accessed via remote access? Also, what do you mean by remote access - not your computer but still on the same intenral network, or are you accessing them from outside a firewall? In either case, it sounds like a port blocking issue. Please indicate what ports each uses.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much about WEBRick or Jenkins, but for Tomcat - if you look at Tomcat 7 source (`StandardServer.java`), you'll see:

```
// Set up a server socket to wait on
try {
    awaitSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 1,
              InetAddress.getByName(address));
 } catch (IOException e) { ... }
```

This means, whatever you specify in address (in your `server.xml`), goes through this.

The [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) of `InetAddress.getByName` says:

> The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or
>   a textual representation of its IP address. If a literal IP address is
>   supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.

If I was you, I'd try setting just the IP address first and see if there are any problems.

The second step is to check whether you have got local name resolution policy incorrect (`hosts` file). I've been in situations where local `hosts` file was incorrect or contained non-resolvable entries, causing all sorts of weird issues like the one you're having.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your remote request are never reaching the services that don't reply. And that implies it's a firewall or NAT issue. I don't think it's a configuration issue since you said from the local machine localhost:port and FQDN:port both work.

To diagnose, a good first step is to see if there is any communication remotely with telnet.

> telnet hostname port

If you don't see a `Connected to FQDN.` response, then a firewall, hardware or the local software firewall, blocked the connection. You will need to make sure the firewalls in the way have all the proper ports open, forwarding, etc.